# Access $(this) from a .toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, this

i have a toggle function like this ( really short just for the Q purpose ):

```
$('element').toggle(
    function() {
        alert($(this).offset.top);
    },
    function() {

    }
)
```

as explained in the code, i cant access the $(this) object values like $(this).offset.top for some reason. please help.

Comment: What does *"i cant access the `$(this)`"`* mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/6abGk/ ?

Comment: edited to show what dosent work.

Comment: @Niklas  - you example work, but try the edited question.

Comment: @Dementic exactly why you should put all relevant code in there to begin with, as this problem had nothing to do with `this` or `toggle`, check my answer.

Comment: you are right, i just didnt figured it out that offset() was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `offset()` function in order to retrieve the `top` property:

```
$('div').toggle(
    function() {
        alert($(this).offset().top);
    },
    function() {

    }
);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/6abGk/

Answer (score 2):

`offset` is a function. That should be

```
alert($(this).offset().top);
```